# PHP World times with BST update

Tags: php

I am trying to show a few world times on my site. I am looking for the most precise way of updating times / keeping them accurate whilst incorporating the BST 1 hour leap.

so far I have

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$uk_time = date("g:i A");
$month = date("n");

if ($month < 3 || $month > 10)  //January, February, November and December are not BST months.
{
$us_time = date("g:i A", strtotime('-4 hours'));
$dub_time = date("g:i A", strtotime('+4 hours'));
$kong_time = date("g:i A", strtotime('+8 hours'));
}
elseif ($month > 3 || $month < 10)  //April to September are BST months.
{
$us_time = date("g:i A", strtotime('-5 hours'));
$dub_time = date("g:i A", strtotime('+3 hours'));
$kong_time = date("g:i A", strtotime('+7 hours'));
}
?>
<div class="time-left">
<ul>
  <li class="clock"><strong>New York:</strong> <?php echo "$us_time" ?></li>
  <li><strong>London:</strong> <?php echo "$uk_time" ?></li>
  <li><strong>Dubai:</strong> <?php echo "$dub_time" ?></li>
  <li><strong>Hong Kong:</strong> <?php echo "$kong_time" ?></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I am wondering if there is a better way

cheers

Jeff

Comment: Using `DateTime` objects will save you a whole lot of headache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. Use [`DateTime`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects (in conjunction with [`DateTimeZone`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) objects. You can instantiate more `DateTimeZone` objects using timezones from **[this list](http://il.php.net/timezones)**.

Example:

```
<?php

    $london_tz    = new DateTimeZone("Europe/London");
    $hong_kong_tz = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Hong_Kong");
    $dubai_tz     = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Dubai");

    $london_time    = new DateTime("now", $london_tz);
    $hong_kong_time = new DateTime("now", $hong_kong_tz);
    $dubai_time     = new DateTime("now", $dubai_tz);

    echo $london_time->format("H:i:s Y-m-d") . PHP_EOL;
    echo $hong_kong_time->format("H:i:s Y-m-d") . PHP_EOL;
    echo $dubai_time->format("H:i:s Y-m-d") . PHP_EOL;
```

The great thing about PHP's DateTime and DateTimeZone, **they do all the magic for you**, you don't need to take DST, or any other strange custom factors into account, DateTime already knows :)

Comment: Went with this. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$tz = $date->getTimezone();
echo $tz->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Hong_Kong'));
$tz = $date->getTimezone();
echo $tz->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

etc...

Heres a list of supported time zones : http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php